# Isometric Tile map Transforms

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flame

Do we have a chance to transform control in the Flutter Flame plugin -> `IsometricTileMapComponent` as in the attached example (its Graphx dependencies but no source code)?

Animation of what I mean:
https://giphy.com/gifs/EInY3MKZ2xvmYNl3fm

Links to packages I use:

- https://flame-engine.org/
- https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.2.0/flame/components.html#isometrictilemapcomponent
- https://pub.dev/packages/graphx

Thank you very much for your precious time

Comment: What has your prior research given you? Did you try anything?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.